# Incorrect conversion of datetime to DataFrame in Python/Orange

Tags: python, pandas, orange

I'm trying to convert Orange table containing one column of datetime and one column of numbers. I have to convert it to DataFrame. I use the following code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=in_data, columns = [ datetime "dateOfMeasure",  "bsnApIfNoOfUsers"])
```

but after it I receive

```
       dateOfMeasure  bsnApIfNoOfUsers
0       1.451693e+09               1.0
1       1.451779e+09               1.0
2       1.451866e+09               1.0
3       1.451952e+09               1.0
4       1.452038e+09               1.0
```

So datetime is completely wrong (second column is ok). When I use print(in_data) it shows `dateOfMeasure` properly.  How can I repair it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Convert it with [pandas.to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html)

```py
df.dateOfMeasure = pd.to_datetime(df.dateOfMeasure, unit='s')
```